# GRUB2 can't see win10 in Legacy Mode and EFI mode directly boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm searching web for last few hours and can't find solution...

I bought yesterday a DELL Inspirion 13 within Windows10. I've manage to install Ubuntu 16.04 after turning off safe boot and switching EFI mode to Legancy Mode. But now i can't add my windows 10 to GRUB.

Boot repiar ends up with error: "The current session is in Legancy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session...." But when I switch back to EFi mode, then my win10 bootup immediately without grub and without Ubuntu.

I've also tried Boot Repair disc, but can't connect to WI-FI from this live CD and also ended up with error about no internet connection.

Any suggestions to work around this problems?

Comment: If you can boot Ubuntu in legacy then it was installed incorrectly (it should have been installed in the same mode the previous OS is, i.e., in UEFI mode). Now, the only way to dual-boot is toggling modes at UEFI settings. Doing what you did with boot repairs will only make things worse. Either keep it the way it is or reinstall Ubuntu properly (recommended): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Boot Repair can convert a BIOS install to UEFI. It un-installs grub-pc (BIOS) and installs grub-efi-amd64. UEFI and BIOS/CSM are not compatible. Once you start to boot in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub can only offer to boot other installs in same boot mode. How you boot install media is then how it installs.

Comment: Thanks for advices! Everything works fine when i've deleted ubuntu, switched to UEFI and then installed Ubuntu again alongside win10.